# Multiple interfaces from a single WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, interface

Can a single WCF service offer multiple interfaces, and if so how would you express this in `app.config`?

I mean one services offering several Interfaces on one endpoint.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First you need to be clear what a service is. Do you mean a single endpoint, or multiple endpoints in the same host?

Assuming you mean a single endpoint, then yes, but with a little work. An endpoint can only implement a single interface; so what you need to do is combine all the interfaces you want to implement into a single interface

```
public interface IMyInterface : IInterface1, IInterface2
```

and then implement them all inside your implementation class. What you cannot do is have multiple interfaces and multiple implementations magically merge into a single endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was asking.

Comment: Simple, Clever! Brilliant solution. +1 from me

Comment: I have two interfaces, do i have to make two services? can i use two interfaces each one has an endpoint in the same service ?

Comment: But we need a class to implement IMyInterface. Then how to include methods of other interfaces in that class?

Comment: @blowdart,    What is best design in case of multiple contracts ?Host is same.We should have multiple endpoint or single endpoint like you suggested.From Client point of view .

Answer (score 24):

The following looks closer to the original goal and doesn't involve one large interface...

Multiple Endpoints at a Single ListenUri: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210.aspx

---

The sample linked to above explains that it's possible to have multiple endpoints registered at the same physical address (listenUri), each implementing a different interface (contract), e.g.:

```
<endpoint address="urn:Stuff"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" 
        listenUri="http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc" />
<endpoint address="urn:Stuff"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.IEcho" 
        listenUri="http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc" />
<endpoint address="urn:OtherEcho"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.IEcho" 
        listenUri="http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc" />
```

This is possible because incoming messages are routed to the appropriate endpoint based on a combination of address and contract filters.

Comment: Actually I stopped reading down when I saw a good answer I could use. I wish I'd seen your response in time. +1 because this is an even better answer, though I can think of cases suited by the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a much better solution for the issue that I encountered.  It allowed me to have two separate types of serializers, which was required for my solution.

Answer (score 5):

With WCF, you can:

- have one service implementation class that implements multiple service interfaces
- have one service implementation class exposed through multiple endpoints, e.g. one service endpoint using BasicHttpBinding for maximum interoperability and another endpoint using NetTcpBinding for maximum performance (with WCF clients).

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could expose the same interface on two different endpoints in your App.Config if that's what you are asking.

```
<service name="Service1">    
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService" />
</service>
<service name="Service2">    
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8002/service2.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="IService" />
</service>
```

Comment: It's 2020 and I'm still using WCF. Is there any particular benefit of having two separate services for the endpoints vs. one service with both endpoints, assuming the contracts are different?

Answer (score 3):

If your implementation class getting too big (like mine) try implement the super-interface in a partial class. You can put one interface implementation into one file. It's merely a convention but could be useful later.