# WCF Add Service Reference

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, interface, service-reference, contracts

I am wanting to know how to add more then just one interface type in a service. at the moment i can only get one to show . I have a few other interfaces i would like to see appear under the service list, How do i do this?

Just found out that because i am a newbie i cannot post pictures yet so i'll try to describe my screen shot..... on my client application i want to add a **service reference**. I can find my **mex endpoint** and it finds my **service** however i can only find one **interface type** assoicated with the *ervice. when i click on the interface type i am presented with the available operations but i am wanting to add more then just one interface type to the service branch of the **services treeview** in the services window of the **add service reference** dialog box.

I am not sure if the words *interface* and *contract* are interchangeable

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find good information from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720376/multiple-interfaces-from-a-single-wcf-service) and also on [Msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6b0acdd3-c5ac-4ffd-b183-38c6aee56cf6/)

Comment: thanks for your response Rev. with this type of inheritance should i epxect see my other interfaces underneath my found service in the add service reference dialog box?

Comment: i have managed to add more then one contract to a service and all seems to be going according to plan. thanks for the verification. i was messing myself with my understand of what a contract is. its my interface and not an individual operation associated to the interface. I am very happy thank-you for your time