# Provide multiple interface in a single service

Tags: wcf, web-services

I want to separate my service contracts from their properties.

Example:

```
IWirelessService 
IWiredService
```

I want my `IWirelessService` implemented in `IRasadService`, but when i add wsdl into the wcf test client, it gives following error:

`Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.`

I want to only provide `IRasadService` as my main webservice.  How can i do this?

Relevant Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWirelessService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AddUser();
}

public class WirelessService : IWirelessService
{
    UserProvider userProvider;

    #region User Operations
    public void AddUser()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRasadService :IWirelessService
{
    [OperationContract]
    BoxRasadWCFReturn GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

Comment: I try to do multiple  interface in my wcf because writting all thing in one interface looks like complex. I mean multiple Interface single webservice

Comment: Did you have a problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: I tried to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720376/multiple-interfaces-from-a-single-wcf-service this way as solution but it gives me error. I implement all Interfaces in IWirelessService but it is not working. İs it possible doing multiple endpoints and only one service

Comment: (This is what happens when I try to be nice). You have to show us what you tried, and what exact error you got, if you want us to help you. We can't guess what error you got, so we can't guess how to prevent that error from occurring.

Comment: I edit my question,may you help me now,please.