# ASP.NET communicate with WCF instance

Tags: asp.net, wcf

In my asp.net mvc3 I have a wcf service with this behavior:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

the service can notify all connected clients with a callback on a wsDualHttpBinding.

I want to notify clients from controller. How I can communicate with WCF instance from controllers?

Comment: Expose a method in the service to notify clients. It doesn't need (and it shouldn't) be exposed to clients too (it could be located, for example, in another interface exposed internally by the service itself).

Comment: For an example of what I mean see [this post here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720376/multiple-interfaces-from-a-single-wcf-service).

Comment: there's a way to avoid a proxy class?